# Lack of connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've connected to SQL Server in one project by the code below(this would'nt work without @):

```
 private string connectionstring = @"Data source=AHURA-PC\Y;Initial Catalog=contactDB;Integrated Security=true";
```

However it worked and there is no problem with that but now I want to use `Ado.Net Entity Data Model` but it can not connect to SQL Server and errors!
Even when I enter `Server name`and `database` then test the connection,it's succeeded but when  I press `ok` it says `The system can not find the file specigfied`

Then how can I connect to it?

I personally think it's because of that `\` after my computer name `AHURA-PC`.

Is there any way to remove `AHURA-PC`?

Comment: Did you try to switch the \ with / and see if that really is the problem? I'm not sure you were right about that

Comment: Post the code which you are referring as `Ado.Net Entity Data Model`. Are both the projects referenced between each other?

Comment: No they are two separated projects I just wanted to say how I connect to SQl in first project, because until when it has`\` does'nt work

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to remove `AHURA-PC` from Server name

Comment: Can you try this: Data source=.; like that.

Comment: no does'nt work